# Get email address from a hash table / array

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array, hash

my question is rather simple for an experienced PowerShell programmer, but I have hard time to get the solution as a novice. I need to extract the `emailAddresses` and `businessPhones` from this object (this is returned by Graph Explorer). In code I am using `Get-MgUserContact` cmdlet to get the contact from user mailbox...

**Graph Explorer:**

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "parentFolderId": "",
            "homePhones": [],
            "businessPhones": [
                "+1 002 224 512"
            ],
            "emailAddresses": [
                {
                    "name": "First Name",
                    "address": "Firstname.Laastname@mycompany.com"
                }
            ],
            "businessAddress": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea/solution would be very helpful.
Tried to get the value of <emailAddresses.address>

```
$mailbox="SomeUser@myCompany.com"
$Contacts = Get-MgUserContact -UserId $mailbox

foreach($contact in $Contacts){
    $FolderID = $contacts.parentFolderId
    $contactID = $contact.Id

    $a = $contact.EmailAddresses
    $a
}
```

It returns:

Address                          Name

---

Firstname.Lastname@myCompany.com Firstname Lastname

Comment: $emailAddress = $contact.EmailAddresses |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address (it works like that)

Comment: You can use Member Access Enumeration and just do ```$contacts.value.businessPhones``` and ```$contacts.value.emailAddresses.address``` to get arrays containing all the values - note this will conflate values from multiple records so you’ll need to check that’s what you want to happen if there’s more than one entry in the result set…